# Pass Files and Object to web api 2 via Ajax causes TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I have an issue  as i want to pass from an Ajax call both an object and some files therefor i cant use  `processData: false`therefor i get a `TypeError: Illegal invocation` is there a way to send both with 1 call please see my code bellow
Ajax Call: (dto is the object and emailAttach is the FormData the files i want to pass )

```
                            $.ajax({
                                url: `/api/issues/${ViewModels.issueViewModel.id}`,
                                method: "PUT",
                                data: { dto: ViewModels.issueViewModel, emailAttach: attachFileData },
                                headers: {
                                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                                }
                            })
```

Web api 2 controller

```
 public IHttpActionResult CreateIssue(IssueDto dto, List<HttpFileCollectionBase> emailAttach)
    {//Proccess code}
```

but when this controller is called the error appears if i remove emailAttach it works fine, any sugestions?

After adding to the ajax call both contentType and proccessData this no longer throws illegal invocation error but a bind error at the controller level see bellow

```
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/api/issues",
                                method: "POST",
                                data: { dto: ViewModels.issueViewModel, emailAttach: attachFileData },
                                headers: {
                                    'Authorization': "Bearer " + token
                                },
                                contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
                                processData: false // Not to process data  


                            })
```

Error

```
      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Does it work if you modify your issueViewModel by adding emailAttach as another property and pass one object to controller? Or create new view model with two properties dto and emailAttach and use it as parameter in action method.

Comment: I havent tried that thanks will give it a shot didnt cross my mind

Comment: One thing am not 100% sure additionally is does it have to be List<HttpFileCollectionBase> or just HttpFileCollectionBase even if its multiple files?

Comment: Nop doesnt work like that either still Illegal Invocation error

Comment: HttpFileCollectionBase only. It contains list of HttpPostedFileBase.

Comment: i have tried something which allowed the ajax call to be sent to web api 2 controller but failed to bind perhaps this might take somewhere? i will add it to the question

Comment: One more thing if you are passing file as attachment you must pass contentType as "multipart/form-data".

Comment: Will try that as well, thanks for helping so far :)

Comment: With the original code adding only that still leads to an illegal invocation i will try with the edited one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141541/discussion-between-mukesh-modhvadiya-and-avaloth-oath).